# Smartctl Message - NVME_IOCTL_ADMIN_CMD: Bad address

Tags: smartctl, nvme, knoppix

I am trying to check certain specifications of a hard drive on a computer with no operating system installed. I am using a Knoppix bootable disk (v8.6.1) to run a bash script with the line

```
smartctl -i /dev/nvme0
```

However, I keep getting the same message:

> Read NVMe Identify Controller failed: NVME_IOCTL_ADMIN_CMD: Bad address

I can run this command just fine on another computer (same model) with a different Linux distribution already installed, but for some reason the command fails when running on the Knoppix disk.

Note: I can run commands like

```
smartctl -d nvme --scan
```

which outputs

> /dev/nvme0 -d nvme # /dev/nvme0, NVMe device

but I cannot run smartctl commands such as

```
smartctl -i /dev/nvme0
smartctl -x /dev/nvme0
smartctl -a /dev/nvme0
smartctl -H /dev/nvme0
```

or any other command that should actually return information about the hard drive. They all produce the same "bad address" message stated above.

Comment: Can you give this command a try and see what it returns? fdisk -l This SHOULD list any disk devices that your live system can read. Then change your above commands in accordance to the devices listed. Let me know what you find.

Comment: `                Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System`
/dev/nvme0n1p1            2048    94373887    47185920   83  Linux
/dev/nvme0n1p2       94373888   136316927    20971520   83  Linux
/dev/nvme0n1p3   *    136316928   157288447    10485760   83  Linux
/dev/nvme0n1p4       157288448   488396799   165554176    5  Extended
/dev/nvme0n1p5       157290496   178262015    10485760   83  Linux
/dev/nvme0n1p6       178264064   472539135   147137536   83  Linux
/dev/nvme0n1p7       472541184   488396799     7927808   82  Linux swap / Solaris`

Comment: Having a hard time formatting it properly, but I basically get a list of devices nvme0n1p1-nvme0n1p7 with nvme0n1p3 having a * next to it under the Boot column. However, if I run the `smartctl` command on any of these I get the same "bad address" message

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar problem which is caused by combination of 64-bit kernel and 32-bit userspace.
There is a [kernel patch for this bug](https://lkml.org/lkml/2020/3/28/10); it is included in 5.7 and later.